# PHP mail with gmail example

Tags: php

I have the following code that I believe will work, but it requires Mail.php. I installed pear mail, but don't have an example of the Mail.php file. Does anyone have an example? I need help putting it in place so that the code will execute. Thanks

```
   require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "<me1@gmail.com>";
    $to = "<me2@gmail.com>";
    $subject = "Test from iyearbook!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "me@gmail.com";
    $password = "password";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     } else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     }

?>  <!-- end of php tag--->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont have to manually write a Mail.php class file. When you install it via pear, it installs itself. Its all about the inlude path, if the include path is correctly set, the Mail.php will be available for use.

Check your pear include path. When you require Mail.php , does it give you any error ? Turn on error reporting and see. Most probably your pear include path is not set

Try this too:

```
<?php
require_once 'Mail.php';
var_dump(class_exists('Mail', false));
?>
```

To verify/fix the pear include path check this: 
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do I check the pear include. Sorry for the newbe question.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ffmpeg.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ffmpeg.so: cannot dynamically load executable in Unknown on line 0

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  require_once

Comment: Ignore those. Those may not be the cause of your current problem. Run my code snippet, see what you get

Comment: PHP Warning:  require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2

Comment: Correct, the last one (PHP FATAL error for MAIL.php ) is your culprit. Check my edit and fix the pear include path

Comment: Stewie, I appreciate you taking the time to help. How is it that I edit the include path? Thanks for you patience!

Comment: check this http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php .. its a bit long, but it will give you exact place where to look. If you get stuck somewhere let me know .

Comment: Stewie, I changed the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and add the following line: include_path=".:/usr/local/php/pear/" I restarted apache

Comment: When I run your code snippet I get the following:  PHP Warning:  require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2

Comment: Hmm.. What is the output of bash$ pear config-get php_dir AND bash$ php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini -r 'echo get_include_path()."\n";'

Comment: probably, run phpinfo() and look at the loaded php.ini variable

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
.:/usr/local/php/pear/

Comment: run this pear config-get php_dir

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ffmpeg.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ffmpeg.so: cannot dynamically load executable in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
/usr/share/php

Comment: That is the result of run this pear config-get php_dir

Comment: I also ran php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini  and goy

Comment: Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: I added include_path=".:/usr/local/php/pear/"

Comment: Hmm.. this means, your pear isnt installed properly OR the right version isn't installed. Run these two commands: php -version   AND pear version

Comment: PHP 5.3.3-7 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan  5 2011 12:52:48)

Comment: PEAR Version: 1.9.1
PHP Version: 5.3.3-7
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0

Comment: seems alright, how about this: pear config-show . .does it work ?  If nothing works, update / reinstall pear

Comment: php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>

Comment: is the a pear config file that I can set the php.ini location?

Comment: great  do this
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: ok php.ini location               php_ini          /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini is now set

Comment: unfortunately still getting PHP Warning:  require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php/pear/') in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2

Comment: Should there be a Mail.php file in :/usr/local/php/pear/ ?

Comment: run pear config-show and see whats your PEAR Directory set as ?

Comment: Just noticed that there is no /usr/local/php/pear/ directory

Comment: PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/share/php

Comment: guess I should change that in the php.ini file huh

Comment: YES, look at your error and compare it with your Pear output .. Your error says : include_path='.:/usr/local/php/pear/' .. It is looking at wrong directory than ( /usr/share/php ) .. CHANGE YOUR PHP.ini !

Comment: ok set PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/share/php

Comment: NOOOOO.. don't change pear directory ! You will have to reinstall MAIL

Comment: still getting  PHP Warning:  require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php/pear/') in /var/www/2testmail.php on line 2

Comment: reinstall php mail? or pear mail

Comment: ok, I reinstalled pear package using go-pear and now have a /usr/local/php/pear

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 18 12:49 Archive
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 18 12:49 Console
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 18 12:49 OS
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Apr 18 12:49 PEAR
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 33897 Apr 18 12:49 PEAR.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1087 Apr 18 12:49 PEAR5.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 18 12:49 Structures
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 19967 Apr 18 12:49 System.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 18 12:49 XML
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14438 Apr 18 12:49 pearcmd.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   936 Apr 18 12:49 peclcmd.php

Comment: I still don't see a Mail.php file

Comment: re install pear mail; pear install Mail-1.2.0

Comment: I get the following when I do a "pear install mail"

Comment: Starting to download Mail-1.2.0.tgz (23,214 bytes)
........done: 23,214 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Mail-1.2.0

Comment: reinstalled pear mail and it fixed some problems

Comment: but now I'm getting PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php/pear:/usr/local/php/pear/') in /usr/local/php/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 348
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Net_SMTP' not found in /usr/local/php/pear/Mail/smtp.php on line 349

Comment: I was able to get it to WORK !!!!! Thanks for very much for taking for much time to educate me on pear.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the emailing process I ended up creating my own function, something like pearMail( $to,$subject,$message,$header,$returnEmail );

```
//To define $to , $subject , $html
//Optional defines  $sender1 , $sender2


//REQUIRED EXAMPLE
   // $to = '';               // Email address of the person the mail goes to
   // $subject = $subject;    // Subject for the email
   //  $html = '<html><body><p>This is a html message</p></body></html>';  // HTML version of the email
   // $filename = 'mail/contact.html  // and create an array called $params to replace in the email.


//POINT CORRECTLY
include('PEAR/Mail.php');
include('PEAR/mime.php');

//INFO UNCHANGABLE
$crlf = "\n";
$headers = array('From' => $sender1, 'Return-Path' => $sender2, 'Subject' => $subject);
$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$smtp_params["host"] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP host
$smtp_params["port"] = "465"; // SMTP host
$smtp_params["auth"] = true;               
$smtp_params["username"] = "YOUR@EMAIL.COM";        // authentication.
$smtp_params["password"] = 'YOURPASSWORD'; 
$mail =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_params);
$result = $mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
```